# Why I can't add a new variable to the Session in Classic ASP?

Tags: session, asp-classic, jscript

So, I thought that I could add a new element to the user Session to add some functionality.

I honestly thought I could do this:

```
SomeFunction(param1, NEWparam)
{
   Session("MyNewParam") = NEWparam;
   //So this would create a new session element called 'MyNewParam', right..?
     ...
}
```

That gets called when the user presses a button and then another webpage loads up.

The result, with this new line of code: The next web page doesn't load. Nothing happens.

Any and all comments are welcomed. 
Solutions or helpful comments would be great.

Comment: Not sure about your syntax but if you are using JScript with Classic ASP shouldn't your collection be referenced with `[]` not `()` brackets? So your line would be `Session["MyNewParam"] = NEWparam;`. You're probably getting a `Syntax Error` but not got errors configured to return from the server in IIS (which is why your webpage appears to do nothing).

Comment: Is this client-side or server-side javascript?

Comment: @superwoman - you neet to set the session variable in asp not javascript

Comment: @allski: No - there's JScript (server side JavaScript) available to the Classic ASP developer as well as VBScript.

Comment: @Paul I did tag [tag:jscript] but some people obviously don't differentiate.

Comment: @Lankymart: Ah! I did wonder! ;o)

Comment: @paul - missed the tag and the point... rushing :(

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is right. However, I've run into an issue before where Classic ASP didn't want to take a session variable if it wasn't explicitly typed though. I'm not sure why this is, but it's worked for me in the past.

```
Session("MyNewParam") = parseInt(NEWparam);
```

Obviously, you could use String(), parseFloat()... or whatever. As I said, the syntax is right otherwise, so if the code isn't working you may want to start looking at other parts of the function that might be causing the problem.